# Merge request: [red-black-tree] and [red-black]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, tag-synonyms

I just came across [a question tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15182383/139010) [red-black](/questions/tagged/red-black); there are currently 6 such questions, while there are 117 [red-black-tree](/questions/tagged/red-black-tree) questions. Could we tidy this up?

I'm well aware of the baked-in tag synonym suggestion UI, but lack sufficient score in those tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making synonyms is for two well established tags that mean the same thing. This means too many to retag by hand.

This should be retagged manually. I'll do that right now.

Edit: done! Tag will be deleted when the tag deletion script gets to it.

Comment: I really should have thought of that myself. Now I am in meta, the more fool I.